# MySQL replication/synchronization: purge from master but not from slave

Tags: mysql, database

I came across this problem a few days ago and have been tinkering with- and pondering about several different approaches, but I cannot seem to find a good answer:

I have two MySQL servers, one master/hot and one slave/archive. All write requests go to the master, and shall also (eventually) be replicated/copied to the slave. However, certan data in the master grows "stale" after a while (say a week) and shall then be purged, so to keep the master's tables short. This purge should however not affect the slave. How can I go about achiving this?

Essentially, my master database acts sort of like a "hot" database, where data is fresh and is purged once it goes old. It should contain data that users might need quickly, and thus we want to keep the tables small. My slave on the other hand works more like an archive, which should contain all data, regardless of "hotness". Queries to the slave doesn't need to execute quickly, and the slaves data can lag behind a few minutes, but it needs to contain all records since our beginning of time.

- My initial thought was to utilize ordinary replication, but can I somehow filter certain queries to not affect the slave? I was thinking of creating a *purge* query, which removes old data from the master but doesn't effect the slave. From reading the MySQL documentation, it seems that this filtering can only be done on Database or Tabel level.
- Another thought was to do this via an external application, and manually SELECT data from the master and INSERT it into the slave, and then use some clever logic to decide what data to select. This works good for log-tables, which will only ever add data, but it doesn't work good for tables that represents states, such as user settings. This approach will probably also include a lot of special cases, as I cannot find a good, consistent way of describing all tables in our database (there are log-tables, state-tables, config-tables and a few which I cannot really categorize).

None of these approaches seem to solve the problem in a simple fashion, but I feel I cannot be the first to have this problem. Any ideas are welcome, and thanks in advance.

*If more info is needed, feel free to comment and I'll edit it in*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use regular replication. When you delete data on the master you do in the same session

```
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE whatever = true;
SET sql_log_bin = 1;
```

This prevents that those statements are written to the binary log. And therefore it won't be replicated to the slave.

- read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-sql-log-bin.html)

Comment: If I understand this correctly, I should call this via SET SESSION sql_log_bin = 0, right? I only want the purging command to not be logged, all other concurrently queries should still be logged.

Comment: Yes, it does that. It only prevents the statements in this session to not be logged. Statements in other sessions are not affected.

Comment: Alright, I'll do some testing with this and if it works out, I'll return and mark this as correct :-)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for this!

Comment: Is there anything that would cause MySQL to suddenly remove rows from the slaves? Like a sync of the tables or something? We were doing this exact thing and then suddenly a bunch of data disappeared off our archive servers